# Problems after updating from Oculus API 0.4.2 to 0.4.4

Tags: oculus

I have implemented my own object viewer using the Oculus Runtime Drive 0.4.2. Today I have updated my driver and I am using the new API. So, I changed three things in my code:

```
OvrGLConfig.Config.Header.RTSize -> OvrGLConfig.Config.Header.BackBufferSize
OvrEyeRenderDesc.ViewAdjust -> OvrEyeRenderDesc.HmdToEyeViewOffset
ovrHmd_GetEyePose -> ovrHmd_GetHmdPosePerEye
```

But Now, the aspect ratio of output windows are changed and the application is not working as it was before. Anyone has the same experience or can help me with this bug?

[image: Before Changing from 4.2 to 4.4]

[image: After Changing from 4.2 to 4.4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the bug. It is really a tiny bug but it took me two days to fix. I was stupid to use the GL_LINEAR_MAP_LINEAR minification filter for my ovrTextures while the image pyramid was not filled. So, I just changed the minification filter to GL_LINEAR. And Now Everything is working fine.

The interesting thing for me is that how it was working before with Oculus API 0.4.2??!?!:)